# Laravel groupBy but keep other values

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-5, group-by

I've been having trouble joining multiple results that I fetch, trying to avoid a separate for each to do this.

Basically I have a table with translations for two languages.
The table columns are:

```
id | service_id | name | slug | lang
```

Example inputs (same services just different translations):

```
service_id: 1, name: 'Igre', slug: 'igre', lang: 'hr'

service_id: 1, name: 'Games', slug: 'games', lang: 'en'
```

Now I'm trying to join these rows based on `service_id` without losing or overwriting each others values.

Example (what i want my output to be based on the two rows above):

```
service_id: 1, name_hr: 'Igre', name_en: 'Games', slug_hr: 'igre', slug_en: 'games'
```

Or something close to that, the main thing is to combine everything into one array field based on `id` without losing other data. I've tried using `groupBy()` but always end up with one value overwriting the other.

**EDIT:**

```
$service = Service::with(['subservice' => function($query){
        $query->leftJoin('subservice_translations', 'subservices.id', 'subservice_translations.subservice_id');
        $query->select('subservices.*', 'subservice_translations.name as name', 'subservice_translations.lang as lang');
    }])
    ->join('service_translations', 'services.id', 'service_translations.service_id')
    ->select('services.*', 'service_translations.name as name', 'service_translations.lang as lang')
    ->where('services.id', $id)
    ->orderByRaw("FIELD(lang , 'hr', 'en') ASC")
    ->get();
```

This is my query currently. Both 'Services' and '**Subservices**' have translations. One '**Service**' can have multiple '**Subservices**' which also have translations. So if I input 5 '**Subservices**' for my '**Service**' I'm actually inputting 10 (5 in 'hr' and 5 in 'en'). I don't want my query result to have 10 results but 5 with the output as I said above in the example.

Comment: You could use relationships or a simple `leftJoin` query

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your query here but I think you may use `groupBy` after your `->get()` method, if not you can check you query by enabling query log.

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog(); 
// do your query here
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();`
```

Comment: I added my query :)

Comment: ok i see the point now, not sure if this is possible with single query, walkaroud will be to use mix of whereHas with DB::table inside, something like that, but i may be wrong im not master of sql